# Can not Solve FinancialDerivative for volatility

Tags: equation-solving, finance

Although Solve can solve FinancialBond for an input parameter (e.g. par) given the price of a bond:

```
Solve[FinancialBond[
{"FaceValue" -> par, "Coupon" -> 0.08, "Maturity" -> 15, 
"CouponInterval" -> 1/2},
{"InterestRate" -> 0.06, "Settlement" -> 0}] == 1722.25, par]
{{par -> 1440.}}
```

it fails to solve FinancialDerivative for volatility given the price of an option:

```
Solve[FinancialDerivative[{"American", 
"Call"}, {"StrikePrice" -> 103., 
"Expiration" -> 1},  {"InterestRate" -> 0.01, 
"Volatility" -> vol, "CurrentPrice" -> 100, "Dividend" -> 0.0}] ==
26, vol]
Solve::ivar: 0.22745` is not a valid variable. >>
Solve[False, 0.22745]
```

This is a serious problem. Am I doing it wrong? Is it a known bug that Wolfram Research is working on??

Comment: `Is it a known bug that Wolfram Research is working on??` is most appropriate for a W forum or for W support. How on Earth could _We_:know?

Comment: It looks to me like vol has the value 0.22745.  Try it after executing Clear[vol];.

Comment: @Ymareth It might seem that way, but if you use 0.22745 as the value for volatility, the option price FinancialDerivative returns is 8.044

Comment: @Dr.belisarius The Stack Exchangers often know what's considered a bug.

Comment: @GeorgeWolfe What we usually do is try the code on our OSs/MMa versions and try (many times subjectively) to decide whether it is a bug or not, and then tag the question accordingly. But we usually don't know if WR is/will be working on it.

Comment: @GeorgeWolfe Not what I mean.  You're trying to solve for vol.  If the symbol vol already has a value then Solve will not work.  Some where in your code (not shown) you've assigned a value to vol and you need to clear it before Solve will work.

Comment: @Ymareth I'll check

Comment: I get better error messages: Solve::inex: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Solve require exact input, providing Solve with an exact version of the system may help. >>

Comment: Works for FinancialBond, seems like it should work for FinancialDerivative

Comment: @GeorgeWolfe, it really looks like it should. I've got the following message (among others) on Win10 V10.3 `FinancialDerivative::checknumeric: Parameters {Volatility->vol} cannot have non-numeric values. >>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And the answer is ... I didn't know how to use the function. If you provide the the price of the option as a parameter, e.g. "Value"->10, and ask for implied volatility, the function will return it.

```
 FinancialDerivative[{"American", "Call"}, {"StrikePrice" -> 103.,"Expiration" -> 1,
"Value" -> 10},  {"InterestRate" -> 0.01,"CurrentPrice" -> 100, "Dividend" -> 0.0},
"ImpliedVolatility"]

 0.275842
```

I got this answer from Wolfram Research Technical Support. It's in the documentation, but it's easy to miss. It's an example in the Scope section. Also, FinancialDerivative will return a list of parameters for each option type.

```
FinancialDerivative[{"European", "Call"}]
{{"StrikePrice","Expiration"},{"CurrentPrice","Dividend","Volatility","InterestRate"}}
```

Comment: good answer, indeed +1; But did they answer why is there a difference in approach between Bonds and Derivatives?

Comment: @garej The answer came in a notebook that was a modification of one I sent to the tech rep that was helping me. I didn't want to engage him in an extended conversation, so I didn't ask. FinancialBond might work that way too, but I was in the middle of a project and needed to get back to it, so I didn't experiment.